# Search a word... in a komodo remote project

Tags: komodo

Is it possible to find a word,... in a remote project ?

I have a project on my FTP, I'm working directly on the project and I'm not able to find anything in "Find in current project".

I'm working with Komodo 8.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, i have 6.1 version, when you click 'Edit' -> 'Find in Current Project...' then enter the searched word and the bottom of the window in the 'Search in' dropdown menu select 'Current document' or 'Open files', then click 'Find all'.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I have to open all files from my project to search something... It's better than nothing, thanks.